# Nginx charset not working

Tags: nginx, charset

I am using easy engine as my server i.e. nginx and setup with defaults, but when i goto my site for text/html the content-type does not show charset

it shows up for everything else, this is bugging me since a while and the seo guys need it Kindly help

The site is built on angularjs the index html headers are

> cache-control:max-age=0, no-cache
>       content-encoding:gzip
>       **content-type:text/html**
>       date:Fri, 08 Apr 2016 10:26:05 GMT
>       server:nginx
>       status:200
>       strict-transport-security:max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;preload
>       vary:Accept-Encoding
>       x-content-type-options:nosniff
>       x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
>       x-xss-protection:1; mode=block

for javascript from the same server

> access-control-allow-origin:*
>       cache-control:max-age=315360000
>       content-encoding:gzip
>       **content-type:application/javascript; charset=utf-8**
>       date:Fri, 08 Apr 2016 10:25:56 GMT
>       etag:W/"5706f1f9-a651d"
>       expires:Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
>       last-modified:Thu, 07 Apr 2016 23:49:13 GMT
>       server:nginx
>       status:200
>       vary:Accept-Encoding

I have tried everything google has suggested and search serverfault/stackoverflow

Regards,
Wenceslaus Dsilva

Comment: Do you mean `charset` directive? http://nginx.org/r/charset

Comment: yes which I have added in the config, but still isnt working